# How to populate a weekly calendar with appointments based on date and time

Tags: php, html, calendar, tabular, appointment

I'm having difficulty trying to implement a way to display appointments into a weekly calendar schedule table (please see below picture) based on the appointment's scheduled day and time. I'm new to PHP and web development.

I'm reading from an XML file of appointments and handling each appointment one by one. From there I am able to tell which day the booking is on. I'm just unsure of how to *insert* it into the table.

Any idea how to dynamically insert appointments into their allocated day and time frame?

[image: calendar image]

Answer (score 1):

How about just inserting User ID in one column and Datetime in second column in a new table. Where user ID is the foreign key from users table. So that one user can have many appointments.

Update:
In case of reading from XML and displaying in HTML i.e. no DB involved

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$VrTableCellTime = strtotime('last monday');
echo $VrTableCellTime;
$ArSampleBookingTimestampsFromXML = array(1374041115, 1374051115);
$i=0;
for($i; $i<24*7; $i++){
  $VrDay = date('D', $VrTableCellTime);
  $VrHour = date('G', $VrTableCellTime);
  if($VrHour >= 8 &&  $VrHour <= 17){

    foreach($ArSampleBookingTimestampsFromXML as $VrBookingTime){
      $VrBookedOrEmpty = ( (($VrBookingTime - $VrTableCellTime) < 3600) && (($VrBookingTime - $VrTableCellTime) > 0) ) ? 'Booked' : 'Not booked';  
    }  
    echo "<div style='border-width: .2em; border-style: dotted; border-color: #900; width:100px' class='$VrDay'>  $VrDay $VrHour $VrBookedOrEmpty</div><br />";
  }
  $VrTableCellTime += 3600;
}
```

Comment: This application does not incorporate a database, sorry.

Comment: Where are You want to insert? into XML ?

Comment: Into the table on the webpage.

Comment: Convert the bookings you got from xml into timestamp. Collect all booking timestamps in an array. Then in a loop generate table cells sequentially. Every cell falls in a rage of time. While generating a cell check if there is a booking that falls within this range, if yes decorate it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sample code would be nice, please. :) Thanks @Neeraj!

Comment: @LBran I have edited the above answer, you can copy and run this code in a test file. Its just the rough code to explain logic.

Comment: Hm I can see what you're doing, but it's not working out for me at the moment.